# How to context click within the canvas and select the context menu with text Remove indicators within tradingview.com using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, contextmenu, webdriverwait, right-click

I am scraping [Tradingview.com](https://in.tradingview.com/) and I'm trying to get my code to right click on the chart but it can't do it.

This is my code:

```py
# import modules
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# class
class OpenChart:

  def __init__(self, driver, entry, tp, sl, symbol, timeframe) -> None:
    self.driver = driver
    self.entry = entry
    self.tp = tp
    self.sl = sl
    self.symbol = symbol
    self.timeframe = timeframe
    self.old_tab_handle = self.driver.window_handles[0]

  def open_new_tab(self):
    # Opening a duplicate tab
    self.driver.execute_script('''window.open("{}");'''.format(self.driver.current_url))  
    self.new_tab_handle = self.driver.window_handles[1]

  def set_up_new_tab(self):
    # right click and click the "remove all indicators" option
    chart = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "canvas")))
    ActionChains(self.driver).context_click(chart).perform()

    menu = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div[data-name="menu-inner"] table tbody')))
    options = menu.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr.item-GJX1EXhk.interactive-GJX1EXhk.normal-GJX1EXhk')
    options[11].click()

  def switch_to_old_tab(self):
    self.driver.switch_to.window(self.old_tab_handle)

  def switch_to_new_tab(self):
    self.driver.switch_to.window(self.new_tab_handle)
```

This is the html code of the dropdown option's menu:

```html
<div class="menuBox-Kq3ruQo8" data-name="menu-inner">
   <table>
      <tbody>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true">
               <span class="icon-GJX1EXhk">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path d="M6.5 15A8.5 8.5 0 1 0 15 6.5H8.5"></path>
                        <path d="M12 10L8.5 6.5 12 3"></path>
                     </g>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Reset chart view</span><span class="shortcut-GJX1EXhk">Alt + R</span></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-DFIg7eOh">
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true"></td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Copy price 1.30655</span></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true"></td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Paste</span><span class="shortcut-GJX1EXhk">Ctrl + V</span></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-DFIg7eOh">
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true">
               <span class="icon-GJX1EXhk">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="currentColor">
                        <path stroke-linecap="square" d="M21.5 14.5a8 8 0 1 0-8 8m6-6v8m-4-4h8"></path>
                        <path d="M10 14.5h3.5V9m-3.277-1.76a3 3 0 1 0-3.993 3.979m14.565-.012a3 3 0 1 0-4.019-3.966"></path>
                     </g>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Add alert on GBPUSD at 1.30655…</span><span class="shortcut-GJX1EXhk">Alt + A</span></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk" data-action-name="trade">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true"></td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk">
                  <span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Trade</span>
                  <span class="arrowIcon-GJX1EXhk" data-submenu-arrow="true">
                     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 16" width="10" height="16">
                        <path d="M.6 1.4l1.4-1.4 8 8-8 8-1.4-1.4 6.389-6.532-6.389-6.668z"></path>
                     </svg>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-DFIg7eOh">
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk hovered-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true">
               <span class="icon-GJX1EXhk">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                        <path stroke="currentColor" d="M13 22.5H5.5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-14a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h14a2 2 0 0 1 2 2V14"></path>
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="square" d="M18.5 15.5v8m-4-4h8"></path>
                        <path fill="currentColor" d="M7 8h11v1H7zm0 4h11v1H7zm0 4h5v1H7z"></path>
                     </g>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk">
                  <span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Add GBPUSD to watchlist</span>
                  <span class="arrowIcon-GJX1EXhk" data-submenu-arrow="true">
                     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 16" width="10" height="16">
                        <path d="M.6 1.4l1.4-1.4 8 8-8 8-1.4-1.4 6.389-6.532-6.389-6.668z"></path>
                     </svg>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td>
               <div class="menu-Tx5xMZww context-menu menuWrap-Kq3ruQo8" style="position: fixed; left: 527.514px; top: 183.068px;">
                  <div class="scrollWrap-Kq3ruQo8" style="overflow-y: auto;">
                     <div class="menuBox-Kq3ruQo8" data-name="menu-inner">
                        <table>
                           <tbody>
                              <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
                                 <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true"></td>
                                 <td>
                                    <div class="content-GJX1EXhk">
                                       <span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">
                                          <div class="item-MkbKmfsi item-jFqVJoPk">
                                             <span class="labelRow-jFqVJoPk label-MkbKmfsi">
                                                <span class="label-jFqVJoPk">
                                                   <label class="checkbox-aOSYFxuH checkbox-MkbKmfsi checkbox-vyj6oJxw">
                                                      <span class="wrapper-GZajBGIm">
                                                         <input class="input-GZajBGIm" type="checkbox" value="on" checked="">
                                                         <span class="box-GZajBGIm check-GZajBGIm">
                                                            <span class="icon-GZajBGIm">
                                                               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 11 9" width="11" height="9" fill="none">
                                                                  <path stroke-width="2" d="M0.999878 4L3.99988 7L9.99988 1"></path>
                                                               </svg>
                                                            </span>
                                                         </span>
                                                      </span>
                                                      <span class="label-vyj6oJxw">Watchlist</span>
                                                   </label>
                                                </span>
                                             </span>
                                          </div>
                                       </span>
                                       <span class="shortcut-GJX1EXhk invisibleHotkey-GJX1EXhk">Alt + W</span>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
                                 <td></td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="row-DFIg7eOh">
                                 <td>
                                    <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td>
                                    <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
                                 <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true"></td>
                                 <td>
                                    <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Create new list…</span></div>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
                                 <td></td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div style="position: fixed; z-index: 150; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true">
               <span class="icon-GJX1EXhk">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 28 28" width="28" height="28">
                     <path fill="currentColor" d="M15 5H6.5C5.67 5 5 5.67 5 6.5v15c0 .83.67 1.5 1.5 1.5h15c.83 0 1.5-.67 1.5-1.5V16h1v5.5a2.5 2.5 0 0 1-2.5 2.5h-15A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 4 21.5v-15A2.5 2.5 0 0 1 6.5 4H15v1Zm7.41-.3a2 2 0 0 0-2.82 0l-.94.95-7.5 7.5-1 1-.15.14V19h4.7l.15-.15 1-1 7.5-7.5.94-.94a2 2 0 0 0 0-2.82L22.41 4.7Zm-2.12.71a1 1 0 0 1 1.42 0l1.88 1.88a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.42l-.59.58-1.65-1.64L19.71 6l.58-.59Zm.36 2.94L22.29 10l-6.79 6.8-1.65-1.65-1.64-1.65L19 6.7l1.65 1.65Zm-7.5 7.5 1.64 1.65-.5.5H11v-3.3l.5-.5 1.65 1.65Z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Add text note for GBPUSD</span><span class="shortcut-GJX1EXhk">Alt + N</span></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-DFIg7eOh">
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true"><span class="icon-GJX1EXhk"></span></td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Lock vertical cursor line by time</span></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-DFIg7eOh">
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true"></td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Object Tree…</span></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk" data-action-name="apply-color-theme">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true">
               <span class="icon-GJX1EXhk">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28">
                     <path fill="currentcolor" d="m13.5 5a1 1 0 0 0 0 19 1 1 0 0 0 0-19m0 1a1 1 0 0 1 0 17 1 1 0 0 1 0-17zm2.31-.6A9.5 9.5 0 0 0 9 14.5a9.5 9.5 0 0 0 6.81 9.1l.99-.78A8.5 8.5 0 0 1 10 14.5a8.5 8.5 0 0 1 6.8-8.32"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk">
                  <span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Color Theme</span>
                  <span class="arrowIcon-GJX1EXhk" data-submenu-arrow="true">
                     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 10 16" width="10" height="16">
                        <path d="M.6 1.4l1.4-1.4 8 8-8 8-1.4-1.4 6.389-6.532-6.389-6.668z"></path>
                     </svg>
                  </span>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-DFIg7eOh">
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk disabled-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true"></td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Remove drawings</span></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true"></td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Remove indicators</span></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="row-DFIg7eOh">
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="line-DFIg7eOh"></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="item-GJX1EXhk interactive-GJX1EXhk normal-GJX1EXhk">
            <td class="iconCell-GJX1EXhk" data-icon-cell="true">
               <span class="icon-GJX1EXhk">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="28" height="28">
                     <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="currentColor" transform="translate(4 4)">
                        <path d="M.5 10.992c0 .287.226.508.505.508H2.65c.19.93.55 1.82 1.09 2.63L2.577 15.3a.5.5 0 0 0-.007.71l1.42 1.42a.5.5 0 0 0 .71-.007l1.17-1.163c.81.54 1.71.9 2.63 1.09v1.645c0 .284.227.505.508.505h1.984c.28 0 .508-.221.508-.505V17.35a7.46 7.46 0 0 0 2.63-1.09l1.17 1.163a.5.5 0 0 0 .71.007l1.42-1.42a.5.5 0 0 0-.007-.71l-1.163-1.17c.54-.81.9-1.7 1.09-2.63h1.645a.502.502 0 0 0 .505-.508V9.008a.503.503 0 0 0-.505-.508H17.35c-.19-.93-.55-1.82-1.09-2.63l1.163-1.17a.5.5 0 0 0 .007-.71l-1.42-1.42a.5.5 0 0 0-.71.007L14.13 3.74a7.46 7.46 0 0 0-2.63-1.09V1.005A.504.504 0 0 0 10.992.5H9.008a.504.504 0 0 0-.508.505V2.65c-.92.19-1.82.55-2.63 1.09L4.7 2.577a.5.5 0 0 0-.71-.007L2.57 3.99a.5.5 0 0 0 .007.71L3.74 5.87c-.54.81-.9 1.7-1.09 2.63H1.005a.503.503 0 0 0-.505.508v1.984z"></path>
                        <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="2.5"></circle>
                     </g>
                  </svg>
               </span>
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="content-GJX1EXhk"><span class="label-GJX1EXhk" data-label="true">Settings…</span></div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="subMenu-GJX1EXhk">
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

the html code is for this menu and the circled dropdown option is the one which I'm trying to click:
[image: dropdown menu]

In the `set_up_new_tab()` method, I'm trying to right click on the chart and then click a dropdown menu option.
The option which I'm trying to click is `options[11]`.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Comment: Done. Let me know if I have to do anything else.

Comment: This question isn't about right-click using selenium at all and falls under *I wrote some buggy code that I can’t fix*. Because when I did `driver.get("https://in.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=CRYPTO%3ABTCUSD")`, `OpenChart(driver, '', '', '', '', '').set_up_new_tab()` then it performed as expected. [Check this if you want more insight on how to debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Got it, @DanielSabrel. Thanks for giving the link on how to debug. I needed that. :)

Comment: @Samaara While running code *Reset chart view* option wasn't available for me so it opened settings instead. So, you might want to *find element by text* as mentioned by *undetected selenium* in answers to be less error prone and avoid confusion.

Comment: @DanielSabrel, There is no "Reset chart view" option in the dropdown menu.

Comment: I see one in your screenshot and html that you added in question.

Comment: Oh, yeah. I didn't see that. 

Answer (score 0):

To right click within the ***canvas*** within [**TradingView**](https://in.tradingview.com/) website and select the context menu with text ***Remove indicators*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/#signin")
  # perform signin and the initial steps
  chart = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.chart-gui-wrapper > canvas")))
  ActionChains(driver).context_click(chart).perform()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Remove indicators']")))
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```